# Windows 10 November update stack on endless Reboot/Restart

Tags: windows, boot, windows-10, repair

Today I started updating my Windows 10 Professional to Threshold 2, but it started restarting all the time, I can't start up the PC. I tried from the Grub2 menu the option "Windows Recovery Environment" and from there the option sfc /scannow in the command line but I got the response: "There is a system repair pending which requires reboot to complete". I am dual booting with Ubuntu.

I am now downloading the Windows 10 ISO from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO). What can I do to repair Windows 10 ? Or even better how can I repair Windows 10 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the Windows 10 ISO from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO), after that I burned it to a CD. And booted my computer from the CD by hitting <kbd>F11</kbd> at the start up. I selected install and then repair. After that i selected the option to restore from previous build and now Windows 10 is again working, but I am not sure if I should update again to Threshold 2.

Tried to update again to Threshold 2 (1511) and again had the restart loop problem.

---

The only way was to wipe everything and install fresh windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

> "There is a system repair pending which requires reboot to complete".

Boot from the Windows 10 DVD or Windows Recovery Environment/repair options, select the command prompt and run this command:

```
DISM /image:C:\ /cleanup-image /revertpendingactions /ScratchDir:C:\
```

(replace C: with the drive where you installed Windows)

This reverts all pending operations.

Now try to run sfc:

```
sfc /SCANNOW /OFFBOOTDIR=c:\ /OFFWINDIR=c:\windows
```

Comment: thanks for this answer, but how can I find out the drive I installed my Windows ? I think it is on drive C

Comment: I always run notepad from WinPE (press SHIFT+F10 to open a cmd and run notepad here) and try to open a file, this opens an Explorer view to see the drive letters).

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd just give an update.  After it was stuck at restarting for a while I decided to force restart, by cutting power.  After that it started and said "Restoring your previous version of Windows".  I left it for a while, when I came back, I got a blue screen saying that the "Boot Data Configuration (BCD) file was missing some information.  So I booted into WRE and went into the cmd.  I ran the "bootrec /rebuildbcd" command, it found the installation of Windows.  So I went through with the rebuild.  After the success message, I restarted and everything was back!